# Is there a .pdf version of the Salesforce Architect Journey fka Salesforce Architect Academy?

Tags: certification

Salesforce recently released the learning resources for the Salesforce Architect Journey, formally known as the Salesforce Architect Academy, for free here: https://www.inkling.com/store/salesforce-university/

Does anyone know if there is a .pdf version available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer for this is no.

The content resides on the [inkling](https://www.inkling.com) platform which does not allow you to export the file into the pdf .Although you can download inkling mobile and ipad apps which will allow you to read the content offline .